# Integrating Chaquopy in Android Studio but facing error ' 'filename' has no attribute 'main''

Tags: python, android, chaquopy

I set up Chaquopy in my Android Studio app according to the [documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html)
I created a python file and stored in src/main/python
This is my python code in the file

```
def main(num1,num2): #this is function definition

    numb1 = int (num1)
    numb2 = int (num2)
    pasha = numb1 + numb2
return str (pasha)
```

Following is the code that is run

```
if(!Python.isStarted())
        Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
    Python pishi = Python.getInstance();
    PyObject pyobj = pishi.getModule("time");
    PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("main",5,10);
    
    Toast.makeText(this, obj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The error that I am getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.digitalsalah/com.example.digitalsalah.SurahDetail}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'main'
```

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a Python standard library module, so you'll need to give your Python file a different name, or put it inside a package.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the name and now it works.